# Send data to the controller when submit from the model and jQuery at the same time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

In my asp MVC form im sending this data to the controller when submit:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Idententificacion.Riesgo, new { htmlAttributes= new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

but at the same time i whant to send this data:

```
$('form').on('submit', function send() {
    alert("hi2");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: '/Identificacions/Create',
        data: { Par: v }
    });

});
```

wtih this submit button:

```
<input type="submit"  value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="Guardar" />
```

and the controller is reciving it in this way:

```
public ActionResult Create(IdentificacionViewModel identificacion,  int[] Par)
```

The thing is that it is sending the parameter one at the time, How could i send both parameters at the same time to the controller.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have/generate two hidden fields for Par parameter with names
Par[0] and Par[1] with corresponding value and delete every AJAX calls. If you have a collection instead only tow elements you cant use a loop for

```html
<input type="hidden" name="Par[0]" value="v0" />
<input type="hidden" name="Par[1]" value="v1" />
<input type="submit"  value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="Guardar" />
```

For that you can use Html.Hidden MVC helper like this

```cs
@Html.Hidden("Par[0]", "v0")
@Html.Hidden("Par[1]", "v1")
```

To use a loop try something like this

```cs
@for (var counter = 0; counter < List.Count; counter++)
{ 
    @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Par[{0}]", counter), List[counter].Value)
}
```